# Mostrar post solo en subcategorias no en categorias superiores

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme

Estoy diseñando una biblioteca personal en wordpress con Custom Post Types y shordcodes de Wordpress, logro mostrar categorias y subcategorias y post, pero cuando intento colocar los post pertenecientes a las categorias superiores me doy con la sorpresa que también **coloca los post de la subcategorias**

**Debería quedar así**

Categorias

-Post Categoria

-Sub Categoria

--Post Subcategoria

**Pero actualmente lo tengo asi**

Categorias

-Post Categoria

-Post Subcategoria

-Sub Categoria

--Post Subcategoria

Tome el código de [aqui](https://freshlondon.biz/wordpress-menu-from-categories-subcategories-and-posts/) y lo adapte a mis necesidades, adjunto código utilizado, me disculpo por el desorden

```php
function mostrar_categoria_fuentes( $atts ){

    $params = shortcode_atts( array(
        'categoria' => 'Categoria',
    ), $atts );

    $post_type = 'fuentes';
    $taxonomy = 'fuentes_categorias';
    // Fetch root categories
    $root_cat_args = array(
        'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty'    => false,
        'parent'        => 0,
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
    );

    $content .= "<ul id='menu'>";

    $root_categories = get_categories($root_cat_args);
    foreach ($root_categories as $category) {
        $content .= "<li class='primer-nivel-desplegable'><input type='checkbox' name='list' id=".$category->term_id."><label for=".$category->term_id.">".$category->name."</label>";

        // Fetch sub categories
        $sub_cat_args = array(
            'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty'    => false,
            'parent'        => $category->term_id,
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
        );
        $sub_categories = get_categories($sub_cat_args);

        $content .= "<ul class='interior'>";
        foreach ($sub_categories as $category) {    

            $content .= "<li class='segundo-nivel-desplegable'><input type='checkbox' name='list' id=".$category->term_id."><label for=".$category->term_id.">".$category->name."</label>";

            // Fetch sub categories
            $sub_sub_cat_args = array(
                'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
                'hide_empty'    => false,
                'parent'        => $category->term_id,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
            );
            $sub_sub_categories = get_categories($sub_sub_cat_args);

            $content .= "<ul class='interior'>";

            foreach ($sub_sub_categories as $category) {

                $content .= "<li class='tercer-nivel-desplegable'><input type='checkbox' name='list' id=".$category->term_id."><label for=".$category->term_id.">".$category->name."</label>";

                    // Fetch sub categories
                    $sub_sub_cat_args = array(
                        'taxonomy'      => $taxonomy,
                        'hide_empty'    => false,
                        'parent'        => $category->term_id,
                        'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    );
                    $sub_sub_categories = get_categories($sub_sub_cat_args);

                    $content .= "<ul class='interior'>";

                    // Fetch root category posts
                        $root_posts_args = array(
                            'post_type' => $post_type,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
                                    'field'             => 'term_id',
                                    'include_children'  => false,
                                    'terms'             => $category->term_id,
                                ),
                            ),
                        );
                        $root_posts = new WP_Query($root_posts_args);
                        foreach ($root_posts->posts as $post) {
                            // Print root category posts
                            $content .= "<li><a href='".$post->guid."'>".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
                        }

                    foreach ($sub_sub_categories as $category) {

                        $content .= "<li class='cuarto-nivel-desplegable'><input type='checkbox' name='list' id=".$category->term_id."><label for=".$category->term_id.">".$category->name."</label>";

                        // Print all posts of this sub category
                        $sub_posts_args = array(
                            'post_type' => $post_type,
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy'          => $taxonomy,
                                    'field'             => 'term_id',
                                    'include_children'  => false,
                                    'terms'             => $category->term_id,
                                ),
                            ),
                        );
                        $root_posts = new WP_Query($sub_posts_args);
                        $content .= "<ul class='interior'>";
                        foreach ($root_posts->posts as $post) {
                            // Print root category posts
                            $content .= "<li class='listado-interior'><a href='".$post->guid."'>".$post->post_title."</a></li>";
                        }
                        $content .= "</ul>";
                        // Final Print all posts of this sub category

                $content .= "</li>";
                }
            $content .= "</ul>";

            $content .= "</li>";

            }
            $content .= "</ul>";

            $content .= "</li>";
        }
        $content .= "</ul>";

        $content .= "</li>";
    }

    $content .= "</ul>";

    //Reset query
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('mostrar_cat_fuentes', 'mostrar_categoria_fuentes');
```